# Migration Questions from Paypal MPL to PaypalMobile iOS SDK

Tags: ios, sdk, paypal, migration

We are migrating from MPL to Paypal Mobile iOS SDK and we have what you call classic app. We could not find the migration guide and are having following questions.

1. The new sdk needs client id. Is the client id same as API Key?
2. According to the guide

"You need two credentials:
clientId: Available on the PayPal developer site.
receiverEmail: Your PayPal account email address
These are used to identify you as the recipient of payments. Both are public credentials; there is no need to attempt to obscure them or keep them private.

Important The receiverEmail should match the account used to get your client_id and secret."

We are not a receiver. We only facilitate payments between our users. Also we don't have a secret key. How do we let our users pay to other users?

1. In our app, user can pay their peers and also service providers. How do we make the distinction?

Your help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Josh from PayPal here.

The PayPal iOS SDK does not currently have support for peer to peer payments.

The `client_id` is not the same as an API Key. You can get one from the [PayPal developer website](https://developer.paypal.com).

Comment: Can you please tell me where is the client ID. I have gone through all site but didn't find any..

Comment: @AwaisTariq it is under the [applications tab](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need support for direct credit card payments (sender has no PayPal account) you don't need the client_id. There is an option in the SDK to suppress direct credit card option. All you need to do is pass the payee's email address when initializing PaymentViewController. You can see the code snippet at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/.

Comment: Not quite correct... a client_id is required to use the SDK. It will not launch without one.